# How to run a loop through organisation hierarchy with an Excel Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with 3 sheets: Invoice details, Proposals, and Employee Details. I am writing a macro that goes through the invoices, checks if the employee can self-approve the invoice according to their band (found in the proposals tab), and fills this out in the invoices sheet. If they cannot approve, then their manager is looked up from the employee details tab and they are listed as the approver, but if the manager's band is not sufficient to approve the invoice then THEIR manager is looked up and so on until the approving party has sufficient power to approve the invoice amount.

The macro that I have so far adequately checks if the amount is self-approvable and can also look up the manager and confirm if they can approve. I am struggling to run a loop through the data that allows the code to keep looking up the next manager until it reaches a stage where the manager has the authority to approve the invoice.

On top of this, my data has over 500,000 rows. Any macro that I write runs fine for a small subset that I am testing on, but I have never managed to finish a macro run on all data as it takes too long.

My code so far:

```
Sub allowing()
     Dim EM, Lim
     EM = Range("TBL_Employee").Value
     EM1 = Range("TBL_Employee").Columns(1).Value
     Lim = Range("TBL_limits").Value
     Lim1 = Application.Transpose(Range("TBL_limits").Columns(1).Value)
     'lim1 = Filter(Range("TBL_limits").Columns(1).Value, "~", 0, vbTextCompare)
     arr = Range("TBL_Invoices").Value

     For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                                   'loop through all transactions
          b = False                                             'flag down
          amount = arr(i, 5)                                    'amount
          naam = arr(i, 6)
          ID = arr(i, 7)                                        'employee or manager
          r = Application.Match(ID, EM1, 0)                     'row in EM for employee or manager
          If IsNumeric(r) Then
               band = EM(r, 3)                                  'its band
               ptr = 0
               Do
                    ptr = ptr + 1
                    fl = Filter(Lim1, band, 1, vbTextCompare)   'filter the bands
                    If UBound(fl) >= 0 Then                     'band found
                         limit = Lim(Application.Match(fl(0), Lim1, 0), 2)     'limit for that band
                         If limit >= amount Then
                              arr(i, 10) = naam
                              arr(i, 11) = band
                              b = True
                         Else
                              If ptr = 1 Then
                                   band = EM(r, 6)              'band of the manager
                                   naam = EM(r, 5)              'name of the manager
                              Else
                                   b = True: arr(i, 10) = "???": arr(i, 11) = "???"
                              End If
                         End If
                    Else
                         b = True: arr(i, 10) = "???": arr(i, 11) = "???"
                    End If

               Loop While b = False And ptr = 1
          Else
               b = True: arr(i, 10) = "???": arr(i, 11) = "???"
          End If
     Next

     With Range("TBL_Invoices").Cells(1, 10)
          .Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Index(arr, 0, 10)
          .Offset(, 1).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Index(arr, 0, 11)
     End With
End Sub
```

Screenshots of tables:

Invoice Details:

[image: InvoiceDetails]

Proposed Limits:

[image: ProposedLimits]

Employee Database Details:

[image: EmployeeDatabaseDetails]

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function i.e. one that calls itself. For performance use a dictionary to quickly locate the array row for an ID.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim dictEmp As Object, arEmp, Limits(10) As Currency

Sub allowing2()
    
    Dim i As Long, ID As String, rng As Range
    Dim msg As String, t0 As Single

    ' put Limits into array
    With Range("TBL_limits").Columns(1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(Limits)
            Set rng = .Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                 Limits(i) = rng.Offset(, 1).Value2
                 msg = msg & vbLf & "band " & i & " = " & Format(Limits(i), "#,###,###")
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Limits"
    t0 = Timer
    
     ' create dictionary lookup for ID
    arEmp = Range("TBL_Employee").Value2
    Set dictEmp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arEmp)
        ID = Trim(arEmp(i, 1))
        If dictEmp.exists(ID) Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate ID '" & ID & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & i
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(ID) > 0 Then
            dictEmp.Add ID, i
        End If
        'Debug.Print arEmp(i, 1)
    Next
    MsgBox UBound(arEmp) & " Employees added to dictionary", vbInformation, "Employees"
    
    ' scan the invoices
    Dim amount As Currency, AuthID As String, arAuth, arInv
    Dim n As Long
    
    arInv = Range("TBL_Invoices").Value2
    ReDim arAuth(1 To UBound(arInv), 1 To 2)
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arInv)
        ' id in column
        ID = Trim(arInv(i, 7))
        If dictEmp.exists(ID) Then
            amount = arInv(i, 5)
            AuthID = GetAuthID(ID, amount) ' recurse
            
            If dictEmp.exists(AuthID) Then
                n = dictEmp(AuthID) ' index to arEmp
                arAuth(i, 1) = arEmp(n, 2) ' name
                arAuth(i, 2) = arEmp(n, 3) ' band
            Else
                arAuth(i, 1) = "??" & AuthID '
                arAuth(i, 2) = "??" '
            End If
        Else
             arAuth(i, 1) = "?? Employee ID '" & ID & " ' not found ??"
             arAuth(i, 2) = "??"
            'MsgBox "Employee '" & ID & "' not found", vbExclamation, "Row " & i
        End If
    Next
    
    ' copy results to sheet
    With Range("TBL_Invoices").Cells(1, 10)
        .Resize(UBound(arAuth), 2).Value = arAuth
    End With
    MsgBox UBound(arInv) & " Invoices processed", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub

Function GetAuthID(ID As String, amount As Currency) As String
    Dim band As String, MngID As String, i As Long
    i = dictEmp(ID)
    band = arEmp(i, 3) ' C
   
    'check band
    If IsNumeric(band) = False Then
        GetAuthID = " Band '" & band & "' for EmployeeID '" & ID & "' ??"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Val(band) > UBound(Limits) Then
        GetAuthID = " Band '" & band & "' for EmployeeID '" & ID & "' ??"
        Exit Function
    End If
   
    If amount <= Limits(band) Then
        GetAuthID = ID
    Else
        MngID = arEmp(i, 4) ' D
        If dictEmp.exists(MngID) Then
            GetAuthID = GetAuthID(MngID, amount)
        Else
            'MsgBox "Manager ID'" & MngID & "' not found for '" & ID & "'", vbCritical
            GetAuthID = " Manager ID '" & MngID & "' not found for '" & ID & "' ??"
            Exit Function
            
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, this is amazing and it works well. Is there any way to make it run on as much data as possible? My dataset has a lot of bands that are incorrectly coded, a lot of employees that don't exist and a lot of employees without linked managers. Instead of the program not running, I was wondering if it's possible to show this in the sheet instead.

Comment: @Excel OK I have replaced the msgboxs with text in column 10. What do you mean by "lot of bands that are incorrectly coded" ?

Comment: Thank you. For example, the employee database that is recovered does not have the most strict data validation. Some bands are empty, some have letters etc. Is it possible to flag something like this up, too?

Comment: @Excel OK I have added some checks on band in junction GetAuthID()